# Parse JSON like string by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this variable which is json-like string, error appear while parse to a object

```
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object"
```

Code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"data":[{"from":"{\"category\":\"Bank/financial institution\"}"}],"statusCode":200}');
```

Seems the function not available for nested `"{\"category\":\"Bank/financial institution\"}"`, replace with simple text (e.g. "123") would be fine, is there any way to handle such cases? 
Thanks.

Comment: String returned from Java Program. Tried to remove "\" but no luck

Comment: @mplungjan: Assuming you meant `str = str.replace(/\\/g, "")` (`replace` has no third argument), that would actually make things worse. :-) You have to remove the quotes around `from`'s value as well.

Comment: @mplungjan: No, it doesn't, [not in the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11). And it [doesn't work on Chrome](http://jsbin.com/ugifip/1), so apparently it's not a broadly-supported non-standard thing.

Comment: It is not standard and does not work in Chrome. I never use it anyway, but was lazy with the \/\/ - I have deleted the comment anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is indeed malformed.

You either want:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"data":[{"from":{"category":"Bank/financial institution"}}],"statusCode":200}');
```

...(e.g., without quotes around the value of `from` and without backslashes) which when deserialized results in an object with a property called `data` which is an array, which has as its first entry an object with a property called `from` which is an **object**: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ohutun/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ohutun/1/edit)

or

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"data":[{"from":"{\\"category\\":\\"Bank/financial institution\\"}"}],"statusCode":200}');
```

...(e.g., keeping the quotes around the value for `from` and making sure the backslashes appear in the JSON, which means escaping them) which is the same until you get to `from`, which is a **string**: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ohutun/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ohutun/2/edit)

Answer (score 3):

The `\` (backslash) character before `"category` is unnecessary.

There's no need to escape a double quote in a single-quoted string.

Comment: I think `from` is a string value not an object.

Comment: @VisioN - yes, I edited from `invalid` to `unnecessary` (almost straight away)

Answer (score 1):

Remove quots for inner object

```
var obj = {
    "data": [{
        "from": {
            "category": "Bank/financial institution"
         }
     }],
     "statusCode": 200
}
```